# Could TeX run Doom?

Tags: tex-core

I know this question sounds silly, but Doom has been made to run in all sorts of completely ridiculous environments, including text-based terminals. So how about TeX? **Could it somehow run Doom?**

I know that TeX is best thought of as a document compiler, but as we all know, it can also be run interactively from the terminal (and recall what I just said about Doom running on text-based terminals). On top of that, the TeX engines have come a long way since TeX 82, and LuaTeX in particular might have some ridiculous tricks up its sleeve that might help make it work.

Comment: Most likely yes, TeX is Turing complete. Good luck finding a programmer to port it to TeX though, and the performance is questionable.

Comment: There might be some other limitations e.g. the compiler might not be able to output ANSI control sequences to change color/move the cursor etc. to the terminal. Not sure about this point

Comment: I mean, there’s an l3 library called `xbox` for a reason.

Comment: (Sounds like something to create variable-width box or similar. LaTeX3 developers are busy people, no time for such things)

Comment: @user202729 I know, it was a joke. `;-)` It’s an experimental box setup system or something.

Comment: program doom in BASIC then run it on a BASIC interpreter writtn in tex https://ctan.org/pkg/basix

Comment: @DavidCarlisle From a performance POV, programming it in Lua would probably be preferable. But that still leaves the issue of the input/output system.

Comment: @Gaussler yes so would programming in C but (even with luatex) using Lua isn't really in the spirit of the question which is, I assume, asking about the expressive power of the tex language, not actually wanting to play doom at a usable speed.